# What is best way to include List<> as parameter in class?

Tags: c#, list, arraylist, configuration

I have 2classes and I want to add a list to it. I will use check boxes to fill in my list. But for now how I should create list?

```
public class DocPart
        {
            public string Title { get; set; }
            public string TexLine { get; set; }
        }
    ​
        public class DocConfig
        {
            public string Description { get; set; }
            public List<DocPart> Parts { get; set; }
    ​
            public static DocConfig LoadFromString(string jsonData)
            {
                var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(DocConfig));
    ​
                var ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonData));
                var config = (DocConfig)serializer.ReadObject(ms);
    ​
                return config;
            }
    ​
            public string SaveToString()
            {
                var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(DocConfig));
                var ms = new MemoryStream();
                serializer.WriteObject(ms, this);
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ms.ToArray());
            }
        }
```

I want to create list for example at start for 2 items. I am thinking of this code:

```
 var doc = new DocConfig();
doc.Description = "bla bla";
doc.Parts = new List<DocPart>();
doc.Parts.Add(new DocPart { Title = "aaa", TexLine = @"\include{aaa.tex}"});
doc.Parts.Add(new DocPart { Title = "bbb", TexLine = @"\include{bbb.tex}" });
```

how should I do this?

EDIT:

Also how can I display list records in console application?

EDIT:
Maybe I did mistakes in my code:

```
public class DocConfig
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public List<DocPart> Parts { get; set; }
        DocConfig()
        {
            var doc = new DocConfig();
            doc.Description = "bla bla";
            doc.Parts.Add(new DocPart { Title = "aaa", TexLine = @"\include{aaa.tex}" });
            doc.Parts.Add(new DocPart { Title = "bbb", TexLine = @"\include{bbb.tex}" });
            this.Parts = new List<DocPart>()
                foreach (Part part in doc.Parts)
                       {
                Console.WriteLine(part.Title);
                     }
        }
```

Comment: just add `Parts = new List<DocPart>()` in costrutor rest are fine

Comment: where I should put it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add to your DocConfig class this:

```
          DocConfig()
          {
               this.Parts= new List<DocPart>();
          }
```

and remove

`doc.Parts = new List<DocPart>();`

also read about [constructors](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ace5hbzh.aspx), rest of your coud is fine.

> EDIT:

to check your list in console you can use foreach loop that is best option to use with List:

```
foreach (var part in doc.Parts)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(part.Title);
        }
```

Comment: Can you tell me how to check my list in console?

Comment: @Mantas I've added some explanation in answere, btw if my answere is fine for you then remember to accept it, all other question can be added here and in your question to not make spam

Comment: Okey, i will last question. Console appear and goes off immediately. Maybe I did mistake in code part

Comment: add at the end `Console.ReadLine();`

Comment: I think the main problem is, that in foreach loop, in line (Part part in doc.Parts) , Program says Part is type or namespace, which can not be found.

Comment: @Mantas replace word |"Part" with "var"